# Node.js createClient Error: getaddrinfo OK at errnoException (dns.js:31:11)

Tags: http, node.js

## Fixed now! The host wasn't found because I was including http in the url.

I'm experimenting with Node.js createClient, however it only works when I set the host to localhost. If I try e.g. `http://google.com` I get the error below. What is causing this problem, could it be a firewall issue?

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var u = require('util');

var site = http.createClient(80, "http://google.com", false);
var req = site.request("GET", "/");
req.end();
req.on('response', function(res){
  res.on('data', function(chunk){
    console.log('BODY:' + chunk);
  });
});
```

**Error:**

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: getaddrinfo OK
    at errnoException (dns.js:31:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:140:16)
Node.js process terminated
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating an HTTP request, and you should give it `"google.com"` as the host not `"http://google.com"`

Edit: It's not an url, that's why you don't put the protocol (http://) to it, it's the host.